# Binding IsRefreshing to IsBusy with Download Service

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

My code downloads a XML file from my IIS. The XML is processed to a list which is binded to my View XAML code.
When I am refeshing my list with the refresh command I want the `IsRefreshing` command to be true while my list is renewed.
`IsRefreshing` stays somehow on `true` and my list isn't updating as well.

Can you help me out?

Here is my code:

```
// ViewModel
public class ProcessesPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        DownloadProcesses downloadProcesses;
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

        public ProcessesPageViewModel()
        {
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(ExecuteLoadItemsCommand);
            CreateList();
        }
        void CreateList()
        {
            downloadProcesses = new DownloadProcesses();
            var allProcesses = downloadProcesses.DownloadXML();
            ProcessList = allProcesses.Processes;
        }
        void ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                CreateList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }

        private Process[] _processList;
        public Process[] ProcessList
        {
            get => _processList;
            set => SetValue(ref _processList, value);
        }
    }
}


// Download Process
 public class DownloadProcesses : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ProcessQuery DownloadXML()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessQuery));
            string xml;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                xml = client.DownloadString("http://x.x.x.x/test.xml");
            }
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                return (ProcessQuery)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }



    // Xaml 
    <ListView x:Name="ProcessesListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessList}"
                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: First of all, you need to change Process[] either use ObservableCollection<Process> or List<Process> and call OnPropertyChanged() in the setter of the property ProcessesList.

Comment: I did. But where. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you share your BaseViewModel.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the order of events you're seeing:

1. You pull down the list to start refreshing.
2. The listview SETS IsBusy to true, because you have it bound with TwoWay (it's not clear this is how listview works, but it does)
3. The list calls execute on the command.
4. Your command is noticing that IsBusy is already true, so it's not executing.

Try setting the IsRefreshing binding mode to OneWay and see if that works (make sure, of course, that IsBusy is raising OnPropertyChanged events). You could also assume IsBusy will be true in your command, and only set it to false when it's done.

If you're still having trouble, considering using a separate property for the list's IsRefreshing, rather than using your existing IsBusy property.

Comment: I set the Mode to "OneWay" and it worked. Well, thank you!